# Are there any Ajax windowing frameworks out there?

Tags: java, jquery, css, model-view-controller, layer

I have a project with a lot of pop-up layering going on and while i will have one layer open, that layer will effectively serve as another window.   I'm currently managing this with _json specific return pages that just return json objects and the layer acts on that.   Each call from the layer is from a jquery .ajax call which processes the json and requests another page.

Is there a more defined framework for this type of MVC interaction ?  I'm managing the creation of the layer, the navigation from layer 1 to layer 2 and the refreshment of the layer with some code but it will quickly become unwieldy.

Comment: Quick comment - I'm using standard POJO/Servlets here.  Nothing big.  jQuery on the front end tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.socialembedded.com/labs/jQuery-Windows-Engine-Plugin/jQuery-Windows-Engine-Plugin.html

http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/

I think these are the two I was looking for.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I used dijit before to do more complex window management. It might help you:
[Dijit](http://dojotoolkit.org/projects/dijit)

Answer (score 0):

Cappuccino allows for some pretty sophisticated webpages: http://cappuccino.org/

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider looking at [Ext](http://extjs.com/).

Food for thought. Cheers.